# How to replace every second white space?

Tags: php, pcre

I want replace every second white space with "`,`" using `preg_replace`. And input string like this:

```
$string = 'a b c d e f g h i';
```

should result in an output like this:

```
a b,c d,e f,g h,i
```

thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can use a combination of [`explode`](http://php.net/explode), [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/array_chunk), [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) and [`implode`](http://php.net/implode):

```
$words = explode(' ', $string);
$chunks = array_chunk($words, 2);
$chunks = array_map(function($arr) { return implode(' ', $arr); }, $chunks);
$str = implode(',', $chunks);
```

But it assumes that each word is separated by a single space.

Another and probably easier solution is using [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) like this:

```
preg_replace('/(\S+\s+\S+)\s/', '$1,', $string)
```

The pattern `(\S+\s+\S+)\s` matches any sequence of one or more non-whitespace characters (`\S+`), followed by one or more whitespace characters (`\s+`), followed by one or more non-whitespace characters, followed by one whitespace character, and replaces the last whitespace by a comma. Leading whitespace will be ignored.

So the matches will be in this case:

```
a b c d e f g h i
\__/\__/\__/\__/
```

These are then replaced as follows:

```
a b,c d,e f,g h,i
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to search and replace characters you can do it as:

```
// function to replace every '$n'th occurrence of $find in $string with $replace.
function NthReplace($string,$find,$replace,$n) {
        $count = 0;
        for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++) {
                if($string[$i] == $find) {
                        $count++;
                }
                if($count == $n) {
                        $string[$i] = $replace;
                        $count = 0;
                }
        }
        return $string;
}
```

[**Ideone Link**](http://www.ideone.com/8ULGr)

Comment: This fails when `fun` is called for a different string if the previous call returned with an odd counter number. Just call `preg_replace_callback('/( )/','fun',$string)` two times in a row on the mentioned string and you get different results.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function insertAtN($string,$find,$replace,$n) {
        $borken =  explode($find, $string);
        $borken[($n-1)] = $borken[($n-1)].$replace;
        return (implode($find,$borken));
    }

    $string ="COMPREHENSIVE MOTORSPORT RACING INFORMATION"; 
    print insertAtN($string,' ',':',2) 
    //will print
    //COMPREHENSIVE MOTORSPORT:RACING INFORMATION
```