# php preg_replace every second occurence

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to transform this

```
329638.798,7387605.001,330131.098,7387324.001,329740.398,7386851.001
                      ^                      ^
```

Into this

```
329638.798,7387605.001L330131.098,7387324.001L329740.398,7386851.001
                      ^                      ^
```

More simply

```
a1,b1,a2,b2,a3,b3 => a1,b1La2,b2La3,b3
```

This means replace every second occurence of comma with an 'L'.

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194818/how-to-replace-every-second-white-space) and tried this

```
preg_replace('/(\S+,\S+)\s,/', '$1L', $geom);
```

without success.

Comment: Why don't you just use `explode` and then use `foreach`? Much simpler.

Comment: Remove the `\s` from your regex and you should be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern you have `\S` - it matches anything that's not a whitespace character, which includes the comma. You can use `\w` instead. Here's how:

```
echo preg_replace('/(\w+,.*?\w),/', '$1L', $geom)
```

Output:

```
329638.798,7387605.001L330131.098,7387324.001L329740.398,7386851.001
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/81422)

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to use regex, use this:

```
preg_replace('/(,[^,]*?),/', '$1L', $geom)
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution:

```
$input = 'a1,b1,a2,b2,a3,b3';

echo preg_replace('/([^,]*?,[^,]*?),/', '$1L', $input);
```

Output:

```
a1,b1La2,b2La3,b3
```